# Notepad++ plugin for both 32 bit and 64 bit notepad++

Tags: dll, plugins, notepad++, programmers-notepad

I created one notepad++ plugin in Visual Studio.It is working only with 32-bit of Notepad++. When I am using it with 64 bit notepad++,It shows error that cannot load 32-bit plugin.Can it be fixed by changing project properties.

Or any other way I can fix it.I worst case,I am ready to create a entirely new plugin for notepad++ 64 bit.Can anyone tell me how i can make plugin according to version of notepad++. I used C++ language for plugin creation.